# What could be the cause of this LoadError while trying to install a gem?

Tags: ruby, macos

This is the error I get after trying to install a gem:

```rb
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: @AlterLagos Thank you! It worked! I've been installing my own gem, probably I messed it up when I added a core gem as a dependency, but I've already removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unistalling `date` with:

```
gem uninstall date
```